# Apache 2.4.10 rotatelogs not able to open log file : no such file or directory error

Tags: apache, apache2.4, log-rotation

I have apache 2.4.10 running . I tried to setup rotatelogs but haven'nt been able to . I was supposed to be a straightforward implementation .

> *Error which i am getitng is :*
>
> *(2)No such file or directory: AH00104: unable to start piped log program 'bin/rotatelogs -v /opt/apache/http-ocfd1//logs/access_log 5'
>   [Mon Mar 16 09:44:53.965524 2015] [:emerg] [pid 7669:tid
>   140328321083136] AH00019: Unable to open logs, exiting*

**Rotation time interval:                 60**

Rotation size interval:                 0

Rotation time UTC offset:               0

Rotation based on localtime:           no

Rotation file date pattern:            no

Rotation file forced open:             no

Rotation verbose:                     yes

Rotation create empty logs:            no

Rotation file name: **/opt/apache/http-ocfd1/logs/access_log**

Post-rotation prog:                (null)

**(2)No such file or directory: AH00104: unable to start piped log program 'bin/rotatelogs -v /opt/apache/http-ocfd1/logs/access_log 5'**

**[Mon Mar 16 09:44:55.515173 2015] [:emerg] [pid 7675:tid 140566727632640] AH00019: Unable to open logs, exiting**

(

i have set rotattion time for 60 seconds just for testing purpose .

**Additional information :**

*Access log does create at /opt/apache/http-ocfd1/logs/access_log   and this file exist .

I am running my server with root user 
I tried doing ls -ltr to this file . 
I also tried to give full paths to log file .

I am not sure why rotatelogs command is not able to locate access_log file ??

Any help would be great ! :)

Comment: I think it would help if you posted your config file(s) as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying back . Issue is resolved now . I had to give full path for rotatelogs command as well  and not the relative path .